# Какой знак препинания после "думал"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Я думал () это он."
Интересен знак препинания.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом предложении нужна запятая, а не двоеточие, хотя это бессоюзное сложное предложение. Розенталь об этом пишет так: "Если первое предложение произносится без оттенка предупреждения, то вместо двоеточия ставится запятая: Слышу, земля задрожала".

Answer (score 1):

Я думал о чём? Вопрос косвенного падежа. Значит, придаточное изъяснительное. Нужна запятая.

Answer (score 0):

Я думал , это он. Сложноподч. предл. с придат. изъяснительным.

Comment: Это бессоюзное предложение.

Comment: Здесь союз просто пропущен,но подразумевается. Вот если бы было" Я подумал: это он.", тогда было бы двоеточие. В современном синтаксисе так бывает, упрощаются конструкции, но смысл их остаётся прежним.