# Постановка двоеточия или запятой в бессоюзных предложениях с глаголами видеть, слышать и др

Tags: запятые, смысл, двоеточие, бсп

У Розенталя есть такое правило: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150

3. Между частями БСП ставится **двоеточие**, если в первой части посредством глаголов видеть, смотреть, слышать, и т. п. делается **предупреждение**, что далее последует изложение какого-либо факта или какое-нибудь описание (в этих случаях между частями можно вставить союз что): С беспокойством я выпрыгнул из кибитки ***и вижу***: матушка встречает меня на крыльце с видом глубокого огорчения (П.);

Примечание. При отсутствии **оттенка предупреждения** в начале БСП данного типа после первой части вместо двоеточия ставится **запятая**: ***Слышу***, земля задрожала (Н.).

**Вопрос:** О каком предупреждении здесь говорится и как определить наличие или отсутствие такого предупреждения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предупреждение определяется **по наличию предупредительной паузы** (в устной речи делается остановка голоса, понижение тона, которые говорят о том, что дальше следует пояснительная информация). Такая пауза нужна в первом предложении, она как бы заменяет **пропущенный изъяснительный союз ЧТО.**

А **второе предложение** короткое, там такой паузы не требуется. Глагол ***слышу*** по своему значению и произношению близок к вводному слову (со значением источника информации). Поэтому там ставится запятая.

Comment: А можно как-нибудь преобразовать 2 предложение (без изменения структуры), чтобы поставить двоеточие? Я такой пример придумал: **Слушаю: сердце не бъется**.

Comment: Или такие. 2)Не забывай: земля круглая! 3)Отойди: темно! 4)Понятно: ничего не понятно.

Comment: И еще, Вы тоже согласны, что в [следующей теме стоит запятая?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/24780/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb/24855#24855)

Comment: Рустам, вы придумали хорошие предложения, там действительно нужна пауза и двоеточие. Возможно, у вас есть способности и интерес к русскому языку. В теме по ссылке запятая стоит правильно. Но к вам такое замечание: вы должны научиться правильно работать на форуме, иначе вам могут сделать замечание модераторы. 1) Название вопроса должно грамотно и четко выражать его содержание.  2) Делайте ссылки на цитируемый источник (лучше всего на Розенталя), а не пересказывайте его своими словами. 3) Вопрос должен быть конкретным: что именно вы не понимаете.

Comment: 4) В комментариях желательно обсуждать только эту тему, остальные вопросы задаются отдельно.  5) Я исправила ваш вопрос (я сама так бы его задала).